# Rolling aggregate for bounded datasets with Apache Beam

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, dataflow

I have a bounded dataset (for example, in Google Cloud Storage). The data has two columns, timestamp and temperature, and doesn't fit in memory. How do you calculate a rolling aggregate (for example, the 300-day rolling mean of temperature) with Beam? I'm not sure using windowing and side inputs would be the optimum solution for a bounded dataset.

Comment: Have you checked sliding windows? It looks a length of 300 days and 1 day period would work

Answer (score 2):

I think what you need is Sliding windows with a length of 300 days and period of 1 day. Since you are going to read from GCS and the timestamp is in a column, you'd need to add the timestamp metadata so Beam knows when the element was "generated", this is done with [`WithTimestamps`](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/transforms/python/elementwise/withtimestamps/).

Here you have an example with Window length of 10 days and 1 day of period (so it's not as big):

```
    seconds_in_day = 60 * 60 * 24

    elements = [
        {"temperature": 0, "timestamp": datetime(2020, 12, 1, 0, 0).timestamp()},  # 1st Dec at 0:00
        {"temperature": 30, "timestamp": datetime(2020, 12, 2, 0, 0).timestamp()},
        {"temperature": 10, "timestamp": datetime(2020, 12, 10, 0, 0).timestamp()},
        {"temperature": 20, "timestamp": datetime(2020, 12, 23, 0, 0).timestamp()},
        {"temperature": 5, "timestamp": datetime(2020, 12, 27, 0, 0).timestamp()},
        {"temperature": 30, "timestamp": datetime(2020, 12, 31, 0, 0).timestamp()},  # 31th Dec at 0:00
    ]


    def get_window(element,  timestamp=beam.DoFn.TimestampParam):
        return {"timestamp": datetime.fromtimestamp(int(timestamp) + 1), "avg_temperature_last_10days": element}

    (p | beam.Create(elements)
       | beam.Map(lambda x: beam.window.TimestampedValue(x["temperature"], x['timestamp']))  # Adds timestamp to element's  metadata
       | 'window' >> beam.WindowInto(window.SlidingWindows(10 * seconds_in_day, 1 * seconds_in_day))  # Window of 10 days, with a Period of 1 day
       | beam.combiners.Mean.Globally().without_defaults()
       | "get window value" >> beam.Map(get_window)
       | beam.Map(print)
    )
```

the output generated should be like this:

```
[..]
{'timestamp': datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 10, 0, 0), 'avg_temperature_last_10days': 13.333333333333334}
{'timestamp': datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 9, 0, 0), 'avg_temperature_last_10days': 15.0}
{'timestamp': datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 8, 0, 0), 'avg_temperature_last_10days': 15.0}
[..]
{'timestamp': datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 27, 0, 0), 'avg_temperature_last_10days': 12.5}
{'timestamp': datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 26, 0, 0), 'avg_temperature_last_10days': 20.0}
{'timestamp': datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 25, 0, 0), 'avg_temperature_last_10days': 20.0}
{'timestamp': datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 24, 0, 0), 'avg_temperature_last_10days': 20.0}
{'timestamp': datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 23, 0, 0), 'avg_temperature_last_10days': 20.0}
{'timestamp': datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 5, 0, 0), 'avg_temperature_last_10days': 17.5}
{'timestamp': datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 4, 0, 0), 'avg_temperature_last_10days': 17.5}
[..]
```

Comment: What happens when the data have multiple records in the same day at irregular intervals? Use a period smaller than 1 day? How much smaller? As mentioned in the question, I'm not sure if using sliding windows is most general solution.

Comment: What windows do is slice the PCollection according the timestamp. With Sliding Windows of lenght 10 and 1 day period, one windows would cover from 1st to 11th day, another window from 2nd to 12th day, another 3rd to 13th and so on. If you have two elements in day 1, they would fall in the same window. Note that all elements with the same window would be weighted the same when doing the Mean, if you dont want this, you could apply a FixedWindow of 1day first and then the SlidingWindow. It looks you have something specific in mind, please update the Q with an example and I will modify the code

Comment: If you add an example input and output, I will modify the answer to more or less match that. I am not sure I understand the edge case you mention